# Options found in locals object in ejs

Tags: node.js, ejs

I got the following error when running the project from [GitHub](https://github.com/Hitman666/MEAN_MVC_2ndTutorial): "options found in locals object. The option(s) is copied to the option object. This behavior is deprecated and will be removed in EJS 3"

I tried to update the ejs and express modules to the newest versions but the notice persists. I googled, ofc, and the only thread about it is [this](https://github.com/mde/ejs/issues/36), but it doesn't help.

Does anyone know more about this?

For reference, here is the whole important code:

*app/views/index.ejs*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="Hack Hands logo">
</body>
</html>
```

*app/controllers/index.server.controller.js*

```
exports.render = function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'MEAN MVC'
    });
};
```

*app/routes/index.server.route.js*

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    var index = require('../controllers/index.server.controller');
    app.get('/', index.render);
};
```

*app/config/express.js*

```
var express = require('express');
module.exports = function() {
    var app = express();

    app.set('views', './app/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

    require('../app/routes/index.server.routes.js')(app);

    app.use(express.static('./public'));

    return app;
};
```

*server.js*

```
var port = 1337;
var express = require('./config/express');
var app = express();
app.listen(port);
module.exports = app;
console.log('Server running at http://localhost:' + port);
```

Comment: this is not an error, this is just a warning, and as the collaborator says in the issue: If you are using express, there is no workaround right now.

Comment: Wow, a downvote, I wonder why. @micnic: Ok, so, no fix right now - thanks. I'll leave the question open until the fix becomes available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr: Upgrade to the latest version of EJS. It removes all warnings about `options` and `locals`.

### `whoami`

I'm a collaborator (or *the* collaborator in @micnic's comment above) in EJS v2. I only started maintaining EJS after version 2.0.3 (or something like that) was released, so I don't know a lot about how the API changes took place.

### History

EJS v2's `renderFile` function, used by Express.js, now has the signature

```
function (path[, options[, locals]], cb)
```

But for compatibility with and Express.js, which calls all functions as

```
function (path, locals, cb)
```

with options mixed into the `locals` object, EJS automatically picks out the locals with option-y names and treat them as options.

But because the Express.js signature is also the function signature of EJS v1, we also print a warning if any option in `locals` is copied to `options`, urging developers to use the new signature with `locals` and `options` separated (it was actually [me who added the warning](https://github.com/mde/ejs/commit/0d3c2bfdfa84a32ba9bb9d52471365f368b9c4ba)).

However, Express.js users do not have a choice in terms of calling convention, so the warning is always present in Express.js.

Some users did complain: [#34](https://github.com/mde/ejs/issues/34) [#36](https://github.com/mde/ejs/issues/36).

At first, @mde (who is the main maintainer of EJS) pushed a [fix](https://github.com/mde/ejs/commit/3134613044c4b11852dc250ff4d52705cf54ede5), which correctly disables warnings on Express.js, and Express.js only.

But then, the person in #36 still complained, as he was using [`filename` as the name of a local](https://github.com/mde/ejs/commit/a3cd2c8508ef39cb998add20ec96a25141023328#commitcomment-9433188), and when the optiony local is copied to `options` a warning is printed.

At last, @mde was like "f*** this shit" and [removed all the deprecation warnings](https://github.com/mde/ejs/commit/cc0c814b7000d91ba72e5ae8ae09609bb573a311), including an uncontroversial and legitimate one, and released version 2.2.4 (the legitimate warning was [restored by me](https://github.com/mde/ejs/commit/c83bf2ea9ffefe9f4b60429a17bd5e730421f776) after the release).

### Future

@dougwilson (an Express.js maintainer) said he was [interested](https://github.com/strongloop/express/pull/2237#issuecomment-70397959) in a separation of `options` and `locals` in Express.js v5, just like in EJS v2. I did volunteer to make that change, but then I got busy so yeah.